# Como formatar data com o nome do mês em português e com letra maiúscula no Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Preciso formatar uma data com o `Moment.js` assim:

```
10 de Dezembro/2018.
```

Tentei assim: `"DD [de] MMMM/YYYY"`

Mas o mês fica com a 1 letra minúscula. O que há de errado?

Comment: Por favor, posta uma parte do seu código, senão fica difícil a compreensão do que está havendo.

Comment: É incorreto o nome do mês começar com maiúsculo, pelo menos nesse formato.

Comment: Em inglês o moment escreve os meses começando por maiúscula porque lá no código está `months:"January_February_March_April_May_June_July_August_September_October_November_December".split("_")`. Para portugues tem duas linhas iguais a essa `months:"janeiro_fevereiro_mar\xe7o_abril_maio_junho_julho_agosto_setembro_outubro_novembro_dezembro".split("_") ` caso o arquivo esteja hospedado no seu servidor, se você trocar essas duas linhas por `"Janeiro_Fevereiro_Mar\xe7o_Abril_Maio_Junho_Julho_Agosto_Setembro_Outubro_Novembro_Dezembro".split("_")` vai escrever os meses começando por maiúscula

Comment: Confira http://kithomepage.com/sos/momento-mes-maiuscula.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como já dito na [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349174/112052) e [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349171/como-formatar-data-com-moment-js#comment701994_349171), os nomes dos meses em português [começam com letra minúscula](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/422).

Mas se mesmo assim quiser que comecem com maiúscula, uma alternativa é baixar a versão do [Moment.js com *locales*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js), e em seguida usar [`updateLocale`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/month-names/), passando os nomes dos meses do jeito que você precisa:

```js
moment.locale('pt'); // setar o locale para "pt" (Português)

// por padrão, o nome do mês é com letra minúscula
console.log(moment([2018, 11, 10]).format('DD [de] MMMM/YYYY')); // 10 de dezembro/2018

// mudar os nomes dos meses para o locale "pt"
moment.updateLocale('pt', {
    months : [
        "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho",
        "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"
    ]
});

// agora o nome do mês começa com maiúscula
console.log(moment([2018, 11, 10]).format('DD [de] MMMM/YYYY')); // 10 de Dezembro/2018
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

No exemplo acima eu usei `moment([2018, 11, 10])` para criar a data de "10 de dezembro de 2018", mas você pode trocar para `moment()` para usar a data atual, por exemplo. Repare que ao [passar um array](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/), os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), por isso o valor `11` para o mês de dezembro.

---

#### Não usar os locales

A [versão com locales](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js) possui os dados de vários idiomas, e (consultando hoje no [site oficial](https://momentjs.com/)) ela possui 66KB.

Se não quiser carregar dados de vários idiomas que você não vai usar, uma alternativa é usar a [versão sem locales](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js) (atualmente com **16KB**) e criar o seu próprio locale:

```js
// criar o locale para "pt" (Português)
moment.locale('pt', {
    months : ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
}); 

// agora o nome do mês começa com maiúscula
console.log(moment([2018, 11, 10]).format('DD [de] MMMM/YYYY')); // 10 de Dezembro/2018
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Neste exemplo eu configurei apenas os nomes dos meses, mas há vários outros parâmetros a serem setados ao criar um locale (como os nomes dos meses abreviados, nomes dos dias da semana, etc). [Veja a documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) para a lista completa dos campos a serem setados.

Comment: Obrigado a Todos,  Resolvido com :                                                                     // Moment
import moment from "moment";

 const pt = moment.locale('pt', {
    months : ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
}); 

export default pt;

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer algo assim para deixar a primeira letra do mês maiúscula.

```
let data = moment(...).format("MMM")
data = data[0].toUpperCase() + data.substr(1)
```

Porém há boas razões para não fazer isso. Em português, os nomes dos meses não são capitalizados. Muitos idiomas não capitalizam os nomes de seus meses ou dias da semana, incluindo espanhol, francês e italiano.

Cada arquivo de idioma no `moment.js` é **"de propriedade"** de pelo menos um falante nativo do idioma. Em geral, você não deve tentar corrigir as capitalizações em seu próprio código. Se você sentir que há um erro em uma localidade específica, abra uma `issue` e aguarde para ser analisada e corrigida se necessário.

Nota dos desenvolvedores do Moment sobre isso.

> Tivemos alguns pedidos para fornecer versões com maiúsculas
>   alternativas, para serem usadas nos casos de exceção de 1) o início da
>   sentença, ou 2) quando se está sozinho como nos cabeçalhos das
>   colunas. A possibilidade de capitalizar ou não (especialmente no
>   segundo caso) pode variar significativamente entre os idiomas. A
>   partir de agora, o Moment não oferece qualquer distinção e sempre
>   aponta para o caso genérico.